# iPhone, Xcode (3.2.5) - Drill down TableView + TabBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, navigation, uitabbar

WARNING: Xcode and programming newbie alert!

Has anyone here had an issue with combining drill-down table functionality with tab bar views? Basically I set up a Tab Bar project in Xcode, and after following [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/45161/1954) (up to Figure 6) to get the first table view in, I followed [this one](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews) to get a second-level table appearing when each top-level table view row is tapped. I have done each one separately and know they both work; however when combined I get the top-level table appearing, and I can touch it to make the rows go blue, but it doesn't go to the second-level table view.

I'm hoping there's a fix to this, or as an alternative, that someone would be willing to post a mini-tutorial about adding tab bars to existing navigation-based projects... in any case, let me know what code you need to see and I'll gladly post it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the mainView.xib in IB add a tabBarController and set the connections as in this picture
(never mind any russian word - they are just titles)
[image]

In this case FirstViewController is a normal view and
SecondViewController is a tableView.

If this dosen't help - post our connections and I'll tell you whats wrong.

Comment: First of all, thanks. Nice to know there are willing helpers out there :) OK. So I opened up my current Navigation-based Xcode project, and pulled a TabBar into the Main Window XIB in IB. Not quite sure how to go about connecting up the TBController and its associated Views to my existing Navigation and Root View Controllers to get what you show above. This is what  mine looks like BEFORE I pull a TabBar in: [link](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0cscj5YkpoMMTMzNWQzY2UtNTVmNC00N2NlLWE4MjEtYmM1YzA3NWFkM2Fh&sort=name&layout=list&num=50) Let me know what you need. Many thanks, Erin.

Comment: after pulling the TBController to the main window you have to expand it. There you will see 2 viewControllers. pull your navigation controller inside (or underneath if you image a tree) the TBController. It should become the selected one. Next delete one of the default viewcontrollers. And you end up with your nav. controller just as on my picture. P.s. a shorter answer would be: "you have to replace the default viewControllers in TBController with your navController"

Comment: Errrrrr... well, I've [done that](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0cscj5YkpoMMjFlYmJmYzItM2FmYS00YjcwLTllMTMtYzhiY2FlNDVmMGVk&sort=name&layout=list&num=50), but the app just completely ignores it and runs without even displaying the tab bar. It just runs the single sliding tableview as normal. Do I have to connect the tab bar to the App Delegate or something to get it to even display first? I do apologise, you've gotten the "stupid newbie" questions, but I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: no problem about the questions:) Please make a screenshot in xcode of the "classes" folder. Also in the AppDelegate.h where the implementation line is - you must add "UITabbarDelegate" so it should be like this "<UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>"

Comment: Ok. [The classes folder - and resources for good measure](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0cscj5YkpoMOTRjZWY1MWItMTE1Ny00YThhLWE5MWUtMmE1YmRhMjFjM2Ix&hl=en). And in the [AppDelegate.h file](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0cscj5YkpoMZmE5MDFmMmMtNWVkMC00MGM5LWJlOTEtNTg2OGY0Yzk1MDYw&hl=en).

Comment: ok. here is the problem! using this picture https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0cscj5YkpoMMjFlYmJmYzItM2FmYS00YjcwLTllMTMtYzhiY2FlNDVmMGVk&sort=name&layout=list&num=50 in IB you have to click on the the line with RootViewController and then in the attributes panel pick a nib file (in your case it's the RootViewController.xib) after saving everything and running the tabbar should appear. P.s. the view should look like on this picture (in my case it's FirstView) https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B7POfcLQnJSOYzgyYjFkNTgtNDBkZi00ZmQxLWJlZGEtYjQwY2JiMDQ4MmM1&hl=ru&authkey=CNafmOUL

Comment: Right-o. I'll have a bash at it and get back to you :)

Comment: *Sob sob*... why does it hate me? ;p [View screenshot.](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0cscj5YkpoMMzg5MzAyNGItMWQ5My00ZTIxLWE2ZDMtY2U4MThiODJiOWRl&hl=en&authkey=COW7zZIP) No luck. In the Attributes panel for the Root View Controller line the Nib Name was already set to RootViewController.xib. I tried setting this for other elements of the TBController, just to try it, but on Run there is no difference at all.

Comment: There must be something I'm just not seeing. I can just imagine you're rolling your eyes by now... but thanks for sticking with it. :) Would it help if I sent through the project files? I'd rather try and fix it myself, but maybe it would help if you had a copy to refer to, to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: ok. I don't get it either. Send the project to stzhuk@gmail.com and I'll fix it real quick.

Comment: didin't get anything... did u send it? I have a dropbox account so you can share a folder with me (the e-mail is the same).

Comment: So sorry, I've been away :) Am sending it now.